# Is not an enclosing class Java Interface

Tags: java

I am trying to make a fan made of an app but when I want to create a constructor with the AsyncRun interface class it gives me 2 errors that it is not a class and I am stuck on that

This is all the code of MultiThreadHelper

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.Looper;
import com.bluesquare.center.provider.MultiThreadHelper;

public class MultiThreadHelper {

    public interface AsyncRun<T> {
        void onError(Throwable th);

        T onExecute();

        void onSuccess(T t);
    }

public static class Helper {
    private static final Helper instance = new Helper();
    private Handler handler;
    private Handler mainHandler;

    private Helper() {
        HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("MutiThreadHelper");
        handlerThread.start();
        this.handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
        this.mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    public void post(Runnable runnable) {
        this.handler.post(runnable);
    }

    public void postOnMainThread(Runnable runnable) {
        this.mainHandler.post(runnable);
    }

    public void a(final AsyncRun asyncRun) {
        try {
            final Object onExecute = asyncRun.onExecute();
            this.mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public final void run() {
                    MultiThreadHelper.AsyncRun.this.onSuccess(onExecute);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            this.mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public final void run() {
                    MultiThreadHelper.AsyncRun.this.onError(e2);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public <T> void post(final AsyncRun<T> asyncRun) {
        this.handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public final void run() {
                MultiThreadHelper.Helper.this.a(asyncRun);
            }
        });
    }
}

public static void post(Runnable runnable) {
    Helper.instance.post(runnable);
}

public static void postOnMainThread(Runnable runnable) {
    Helper.instance.postOnMainThread(runnable);
}

public static <T> void post(AsyncRun<T> asyncRun) {
    Helper.instance.post(asyncRun);
}
```

And this is the part where I get the 2 errors

```
        public void a(final AsyncRun asyncRun) {
            try {
                final Object onExecute = asyncRun.onExecute();
                this.mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public final void run() {
                        MultiThreadHelper.AsyncRun.this.onSuccess(onExecute);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
                this.mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public final void run() {
                        MultiThreadHelper.AsyncRun.this.onError(e2);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong or is there a solution?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the complete error message.